# How do I set the color in Attributed button in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I want to set a title to be underlined with a custom color in an `UIButton`, `NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorWithRed:38 green:105 blue:255 alpha:1]` is not applied in my button.

```
NSDictionary *attrDict = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14],NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:38 green:105 blue:255 alpha:1], NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)};

NSMutableAttributedString *mat = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:linkUrl];
[mat addAttributes:attrDict range:NSMakeRange (0, mat.length)];
[self.weblink setAttributedTitle:mat forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line only

```
  float w = 255.0;
   NSDictionary *attrDict = @{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14],NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor colorWithRed:38/w green:105/w blue:255/w alpha:1], NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)};
```

Comment: You really should declare `w` as a `CGFloat`, not just `float` so its type matches that of the `UIColor` parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The RGB values for `UIColor` need to be in the range `0.0` to `1.0`. The color you are creating will appear as white. You need:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:38/255.0 green:105/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1]
```